# How can you play an AudioFile that will keep playing even if you navigate through pages in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make like my own music app. With my dependency service solution in iOS i can hear the mp3 just fine but once I navigate through other pages the file stops. So my question is, how can I make so the file keeps playing even if i navigate through different pages after i "play" it?

This is my code:
My button where I pick the "track".

```
async void PlayThisSongButton (object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IPlayerVoice>().PlayAudioFile("myfilename.mp3");
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface IPlayerVoice
{
    void PlayAudioFile(string fileName);
}
```

Dependency service iOS:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof (VoicePlayer_iOS))]

namespace myProject.iOS
{
  public class VoicePlayer_iOS : IPlayerVoice
  {
    AVAudioPlayer player;

    public VoicePlayer_iOS()
    {
    }

    public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
    {
        string sFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource
        (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
        var url = NSUrl.FromString(sFilePath);
        var _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
        _player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) =>
        {
            _player = null;
        };
        _player.Play();
     }

   }
}
```

So with this current code. I click on my button where i start the audiofile. I then navigate to a different page. The audiofile stops. Any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: You need to register your VoicePlayer as a service in the IOC container (and maybe make that PlayAudioFile async) like it's explained here : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39064/use-ioc-in-ios-and-forms-at-the-same-time-xlabs

Comment: @yanyankelevich watched the link and i kinda understand. not sure how i would adjust my current code in order to make it work though. i would very much appreciate an example

Comment: There you go : https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleAudioForms/tree/master/SimpleAudioForms (without IOC but i believe it still works )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never worked with audio in Xamarin Forms but looked into it once.

I think the comment from @yanyankelevich with a GitHub link would still stop the audio when the user navigates away from the page.

As @yanyankelevich suggested though, using a background service might be your best bet. Some links for that (there is a lot of code so I will not duplicate it in this post):

[iOS AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/) (specifically check out the `PlayBackgroundMusic` method and the other background related methods below that one)

[Android Background Audio Streaming](https://blog.xamarin.com/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin-android/)

For a super simple way of doing it (which I do not suggest and have not ever tried), have you tried just running your method within a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` which will do a fire and forget?

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DependencyService.Get<IPlayerVoice>().PlayAudioFile("myfilename.mp3"));
```

Comment: Tried that code snippet but then there was no sound at all. I will check out your links! :)

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Try my edit of the simple example (not sure if the audio code needs to run on the UI Thread or not...)

Comment: I love how a task that simple and that usual can turn into a madness of code when you mix xamarin forms and IOS.

Comment: @yanyankelevich Haha completely agree, though I blame iOS more than Xamarin. Especially on iOS, they started out as iPods... they should have that stuff down perfectly by now ;)

Comment: It stops when i push to other pages but i do get a sound from the command

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to Use MVVM or MVC and run the music on the main view.

this will allow you to browse the app, while your music still plays.

basically have the Main view and create a grid that you place your "browserView"
in, add all the normal code you would use for the app to the viewmodel of the browser.

then add the code for the music to the viewmodel of the mainview.

Just make sure to add the functionality to pause the music.

Comment: The OP is asking about playing audio on Xamarin Forms (which is a native app) not through a website.

Comment: Right but you are talking about browsers and are talking about methods that do not work the same way in Xamarin Forms that they might work in a website.

Comment: I just used the name "browserView", to explain that the named view will be the one that is going to browse around his app.

Comment: Understood. I guess generally your answer could work for multiple platforms.